# kibana 4 search place out of iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, keypress, kibana-4

kibana 4 search code looks like following

```
<form name="queryInput" class="fill inline-form ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-submit="filterResults()">

      <div class="typeahead ng-isolate-scope" kbn-typeahead="dashboard">
        <div class="input-group" ng-class="queryInput.$invalid ? 'has-error' : ''">

          <input input-focus="" placeholder="Filter..." class="form-control ng-isolate-scope ng-valid ng-valid-query-input ng-dirty" ng-model="state.query" kbn-typeahead-input="" validate-query="" type="text"><i style="display: none;" class="fa fa-ban input-error"></i>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="queryInput.$invalid">
            <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="typeahead.isVisible()" ng-mouseenter="typeahead.setMouseover(true);" ng-mouseleave="typeahead.setMouseover(false);" class="typeahead-items ng-hide">

  <!-- ngRepeat: item in typeahead.getItems() --><div ng-repeat="item in typeahead.getItems()" ng-class="{active: item === typeahead.active}" ng-click="typeahead.selectItem(item, $event);" ng-mouseenter="typeahead.activateItem(item);" class="typeahead-item ng-binding ng-scope">
    *
  </div><!-- end ngRepeat: item in typeahead.getItems() -->
</div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

I have kibana dashboard in iframe in my page.
I want to have following code out of that iframe and want it to have functionality same as above code.

```
<input id="logsSearch" name="logsSearch" type="text"/>
```

to achieve this i have tried following options.

```
'keypress #logsSearch'  : function(e){
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {

                    var strSearch = $("#logsSearch").val();
                    $("#kibana").contents().find('form[name=queryInput]').find('input').val(strSearch);
                    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
                    e.which = 13; // # Some key code value
                    $("#kibana").contents().find('form[name=queryInput]').find('input').trigger(e);
                    $("#kibana").contents().find('form[name=queryInput]').find('button').click();
                }

}
```

but it doesn't work. it calls /kibana4/elasticsearch/_msearch

but it doesn't call __kibanaQueryValidator.

in other solution i tried to trigger keyup, keydown events as well. but it also doesn't work

I don't know how should I do it. Any ideas or pointers or guidance to solve this problem will be a great help.